# Executing asp.net core EF migration in a class library without hardcoding connection string

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-core, environment-variables

I would like to execute migration in separate environments. I'm working with Entity Framework and ASP.NET Core. For now I have this :

```
public class TemporaryDbContextFactory : IDbContextFactory<ApplicationDbContext>
{
    public ApplicationDbContext Create(DbContextFactoryOptions options)
    {
        var builder = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<ApplicationDbContext>();
        builder.UseSqlServer("Data Source=.\\LOCALHOST;Initial Catalog=MyDB;Integrated Security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true");

        return new ApplicationDbContext(builder.Options);
    }
}
```

This code is in a DAL class library who separate the database interactions from the server code.

It's ok to use this when executing migrations but I don't really like doing it like this.

The problem here is that I use a local database for development but we also have a development server and a staging server with different connection strings. What I can't manage to do is to find a way to not hardcode the connection strings in that class.

Is there a way to configure the connection strings for different environments and indicate which to use when executing the migrations ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can use environment variables for this.

Thats why you have `appsettings.<EnvironmentName>.json`

[Configuration in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration)
Not bad Microsoft article abount [Working with multiple environments](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/environments)

FYI
[Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.environment.getenvironmentvariable(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: I knew that I can configure it like this, that's what i did but how can I specify which environment I'm in when executing migration ?

Comment: @AntoineThiry Set ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT before executing migration

Comment: Thanks, I missed that part, shouldn't have ask this obvious question...

Answer (score 1):

You need to inject `DbContextOptionsBuilder<ApplicationDbContext>` into your factory constructor and then configure the DbContext in the main application's `Startup.cs`

```
public class TemporaryDbContextFactory : IDbContextFactory<ApplicationDbContext>
{
    private readonly DbContextOptionsBuilder<ApplicationDbContext> optionsBuilder;

    public TemporaryDbContextFactory(DbContextOptionsBuilder<ApplicationDbContext> optionsBuilder)
    {
        if(optionsBuilder==null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(optionsBuilder));

        this.optionsBuilder = optionsBuiler;
    }

    public ApplicationDbContext Create(DbContextFactoryOptions options)
    {
        return new ApplicationDbContext(optionsBuilder.Options);
    }
}
```

And in Startup.cs:

```
services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options => {
    options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("MyConnectionString"));
});
```

`Configuration.GetConnectionString("MyConnectionString")` is shorthand for `Configuration["ConnectionStrings:MyConnectionString"]`.